# Как обращаться к элементу структуры помещенной в вектор через итератор?

Tags: c++

допустим есть структура point c двумя переменными типа double(координаты x и y), несколько таких точек помещены в вектор points, как обратится например к координате x через итератор этого вектора? Извиняюсь если что-то не так объяснил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct point { double x, y; };

vector<point> points;

....

for(auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "(" << it->x << "," << it->y << ")\n";
}
```

Что-то в этом роде.